# host.docker.internal in production environment

Tags: docker, prometheus, production-environment, open-telemetry

I am trying to set up opentelemetry for my core java based application. I am using docker to launch containers for grafana,tempo,loki and prometheus services. I want to export the metrics to prometheus which I have configured as a datasource in Grafana. In the development environment, I have used the following VM options and prometheus config file changes.
**VM Options**:
`-javaagent:C:\Users\A***.***\Downloads\opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://localhost:4317 -Dotel.service.name=auto-compensation-service -Dotel.exporter.otlp.insecure=true -Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp -Dotel.metrics.exporter=prometheus -Dotel.instrumentation.runtime-metrics.enabled=true -Dotel.exporter.prometheus.host=localhost -Dotel.exporter.prometheus.port=9464` 
**Prometheus config :**
`global:
scrape_interval: 30s
scrape_timeout: 20s
evaluation_interval: 15s

```
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: 'my-service'
   static_configs:
   - targets: [ 'host.docker.internal:9464']
   `
```

It is working fine in the development environment. Now I want to test it in the production environment. So what should be the host name I should be using instead of "host.docker.internal"?
In the production setup, grafana, tempo, loki and prometheus containers are launched by another application and I want that prometheus server to scrape the metrics from my application. So what are the changes I have to make in the current setup?

I tried in the development environment and is able to see the metrics data getting exported to the Prometheus datasource. Now I want to test on the production environment. So should I provide the IP of my machine as the hostname in the production environment? My machine is having a dynamic IP address, so will that be an issue ?

Please feel free to give your suggestions/opinions/views on this.
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your production topology and its technologies which are used. generally it doesnt matter what is your host IP because you dont have to use dynamic IP for your routing,actually you need a service discovery but if you want to use docker you need to discover your service manually, you can define a network interface between your application and your prometheus and use hostname for your connections.
remember you need to set hostname on your image permanently

Comment: My application is not container based. Only for grafana datasources, I am using docker

Comment: you can make an interface in your docker which is in the same namespace with your host, for example you can use bridge interface

Comment: Okay. I think my question was not clear to you. I used `host.docker.internal` as host name because I am using docker desktop in my dev environment. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host . But for the production environment, i will not be using docker desktop. My application will be part of a bigger setup in which the main application will be launching all these  docker containers . So my question is that , in the production environment, can I replace `host.docker.internal` with the IP address of the machine?

Comment: you can use the hostname of your machine , just set the hostname on your machine ,  cause of their same namespace your docker containers can detect the hostname of your host

Comment: I have got one more question. Currently in the VM options I am passing the host as `localhost` . But when i don't provide that properties during runtime also, it works well in my local machine in development environment. So my question is that can I follow the same approach in case of production environment as well? That is, without the `-Dotel.exporter.prometheus.host` property. And only providing `<my-host-ip>:9464` in the targets section of scrape job.